# Nodejs render https gcloud

Tags: node.js, https

I have deployed a webapp on gcloud. I am able to access both http and https. But default it uses http.

Upon get/post of particular  request I want the redirect using https rather that http. Is there easy way to do this.

```
app.get('/login',
  function(req, res){
    res.render('login');
  });
```

On google cloud I have deployed Nodejs server built using express framework(http only) However I am able to make http and https requests to the server both yielding the same result. Is there a way while making to calls for a particular request, in this case '/', I can be redirected 'login' with 'https' instead of 'http'... now i get redirected to 'http://server/login' i want to go to 'https://server/login' without writing a https server

I understand that i might need to build 'https' server like the below. is there a way i can avoid this.

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World!");
});

var sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(sslOptions, server).listen(8443)
```

Comment: Check whether the request is HTTP, then serve a redirect response.

Comment: I am looking for syntax for rendering a response as HTTPS

Comment: HTTPS comes from the _request_.  You need to redirect to an HTTPS URL.

Comment: edited the Qs please check

Comment: Your cloud provider is probably already accepting HTTPS requests.  You just need to serve a redirect response.

Comment: could you share code snippet.. for the same...I am new to Nodejs and javascript... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is specific to gcloud. I resolved it by adding below in app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: IGNORED
  secure: always
```